# finding words in past tense using lex

Tags: lex

I want to know how to write a code in lex to identify and print the words in past tense. I have written a sample code but it doesnt print the word though it identifies the words in past tense. Pls help

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
%}
%%
[a-zA-Z]"ed" {printf("%s is in past tense\n",yytext);}
[a-zA-Z0-9,$.]
%%
main()
{
yyin = fopen("pos.c","r");
yylex();
}
```

When i gave the following as input:
    wanted loved gained maintained decided received
This is the output i got:
        ted is in past tense
        ved is in past tense
        ned is in past tense
        ned is in past tense
        ded is in past tense
        ved is in past tense
This is the required output:
        wanted is in past tense
        loved is in past tense
        gained is in past tense
        maintained is in past tense
        decided is in past tense
        received is in past tense

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern asked to match a single letter followed by `ed`, so that's what got printed.  To match (and thus print) the whole word, you'd need a pattern like `[a-zA-Z]+` to match the whole word.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the mistake.. i didn't notice that.. :)

Comment: how do i print the root word given its past tense? For eg: If loved is the word given as input then to get the output as "the root word is love" how can i modify this code?

Comment: @user3527594: That's not what your question asked; your desired output was the past-tense words.  But since you know that the root is just the past-tense word with the trailing "ed" removed, it shouldn't be hard.